# JsonIgnore doesn't work for MemberSerialization.Fields in Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize an object with Newtonsoft.Json by using the Fields from the MemberSerialization enum.

This is the class where [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]  is added:

```
 [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)] 
        public class Employee {
            [JsonIgnore]
            public int ID { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty]
            public string Name { get; set; } 
            public char Gender { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty]
            public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
            private string Address { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty]
            public List<string> Skills { get; set; }         
        }
```

//Main part:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee() {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "Igor",
                Gender = 'M',
                WorkPhone = "78123456",
                Skills = new List<string>() { "C#", "SQL Server" }
            };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees, Formatting.Indented);
                string path = @"..\JsonSerialization.json";
                File.WriteAllText(path, json);
```

Serialization gives an output which is not expected:

```
[
  {
    "<ID>k__BackingField": 1,
    "<Name>k__BackingField": "Igor",
    "<Gender>k__BackingField": "M",
    "<WorkPhone>k__BackingField": "78123456",
    "<Address>k__BackingField": "ul. Partizanski odredi, Skopje",
    "<Skills>k__BackingField": [
      "C#",
      "SQL Server"
    ]
  } 
]
```

If I comment the class attribute

```
//[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]
```

then the functionality works.
Any thoughts about this, why it's that? I can't find it specified in the Newtonsoft.Json documentation.

However, the JsonIgnore attribute works fine with

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)] 
and
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
```

Comment: In c# 7.3 you should be able to add `[field: JsonIgnore]` to the properties to mark the secret backing fields as ignored.  See [Auto-Implemented Property Field-Targeted Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/auto-prop-field-attrs) and [What's new in C# 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3).

Answer (score 3):

When you use an auto-property (i.e. `{ get; set; }`), *"the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors"* [(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

What you're seeing here is those private backing fields, as the docs for [MemberSerialization.Fields](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MemberSerialization.htm) say - *"**All public and private fields are serialized.**"*

As all your properties are public and you have no fields in your class, why would you set that value anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Even if I have fields and auto-properties, I expect only the fields to be serialized. However, the auto-properties are there also. It was just tried and we didn't expect any properties data in a serialized file. Now it's clear why the k__BackingField is there. Thanks!